# How do I group by date and add a count if there are duplicates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a dataset like this:

```
[
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-20"
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-14"
    },
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-13",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-13",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09"
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    }
]
```

What I want to do is group this by `createdAt` and if there are duplicates keys within said date, add the duplicates together. For example:

```
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-13",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-13",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
```

will be

```js
{
  'Tired': 2,
  'Anxious': 2,
  'createdAt': '2021-12-13'
}
```

Another example:

```js
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    }
```

will look like

```js
{
  'Sad': 3,
  'Anxious': 7,
  'Happy': 5,
  'Tired': 2,
  'Energetic': 1,
  'createdAt': '2021-12-08',
}
```

I was able to get the dataset like this so far:

```js
response.value.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[toMoodMap(val) as string] = acc[val] === undefined ? 1 : (acc[val] += 1);
  acc['createdAt'] = assessment.createdAt;
  moodArr.push(acc);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

I'm aware of lodash's groupBy, but it's currently not available to me unfortunately. Is there a way to achieve the end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where `createdAt` is the key and the grouped object is the value.

  - In every iteration, using [`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get), get the map value which key is the current `createdAt`, otherwise a fallback object with `createdAt`.
  - Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), iterate over the rest of the current object's properties and increment the values.
  - Using [`Map#set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set), update the current pair.
- Using [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), return the list of grouped objects by `createdAt`.

```js
const arr = [ { "Sad": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Happy": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Anxious": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Happy": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Tired": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Energetic": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Anxious": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Happy": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Sad": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Happy": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Happy": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Anxious": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Sad": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Anxious": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Anxious": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Tired": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Anxious": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" }, { "Anxious": 1, "createdAt": "2021-12-08" } ];

const res = [...
  arr.reduce((map, { createdAt, ...e }) => {
    const current = map.get(createdAt) ?? { createdAt };
    Object.entries(e).forEach(([key, value]) => current[key] = (current[key] ?? 0) + value);
    map.set(createdAt, current);
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your array is called `data`:

```
// let's create an object with keys equals to all created dates, values are all items with that date.
const grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((res, item) => {
  const groupedItem = Object.keys(item).reduce((group, key) => {
    if (key === 'createdAt') {
      return group;
    }
    const value = item[key];
    if (isNaN(value)) { // if the value is not a number
      return group;
    }
    return {
      ...group,
      [key]: (group[key] || 0) + value,
    };
  }, res[item.createdAt] || {createdAt: item.createdAt});
  

  return {
    ...res,
    [item.createdAt]: groupedItem,
  };
}, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing correct! You just want to obtain array from the final grouped object using `Object.values` rather than pushing it inside `.reduce` itself.

```
const arr = [
    ... Your Array
];

groupedItems = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {

    const key = curr["createdAt"];

    if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = {}

    for (let i in curr) {
        if (i === "createdAt") {
            acc[key][i] = curr[i]
        } else {
            acc[key][i] = (acc[key][i] || 0) + 1
        }
    }

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(groupedItems))
```

Comment: `groupedItems = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {}));` so, it will always give the array back?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this manually.

First, break it down by extracting all the different createdAt's (into a set to avoid duplicates).
Then, for each createdAt, get all the existing keys.
For each key, count the occurrences.

Here is the beginning of the code, how I would do it. I hope this already helps, I have no time to finish that code up right now, but let me know it you are able to do it with this approach.

Code:

```
const data = [
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-20"
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-14"
    },
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-13",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-13",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09",
        "Anxious": 1
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-09"
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Energetic": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Happy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Sad": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Tired": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    },
    {
        "Anxious": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-08"
    }
]

const createdAts = new Set()
data.forEach(datum => {
    createdAts.add(datum.createdAt);
});

const dataTranformed = [];

createdAts.forEach(createdAt => {
    // This array contains all data entries, for one createdAt-date
    const dataFiltered = data.filter((datum) => datum.createdAt === createdAt);
    
    // Here you will have to create a new object and add all the keys & values from dataFiltered (&increment numbers if an key already exists)
    // Add this Object to the dataTransformed list and you are done
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group by destructured `createdAt` and collect count for each key/value pair of the rest object.

```js
const
    data = [{ Happy: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-20" }, { Tired: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-14" }, { Energetic: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-13", Anxious: 1 }, { Energetic: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-13", Anxious: 1 }, { Tired: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-09", Anxious: 1 }, { Tired: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-09", Anxious: 1 }, { Sad: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-09" }, { Sad: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Happy: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Anxious: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Happy: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Tired: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Energetic: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Anxious: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Happy: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Sad: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Happy: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Happy: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Anxious: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Sad: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Anxious: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Anxious: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Tired: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Anxious: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }, { Anxious: 1, createdAt: "2021-12-08" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { createdAt, ...o }) => {
        r[createdAt] ??= { createdAt };
        Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([k, v]) => r[createdAt][k] = (r[createdAt][k] || 0) + v);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say your this is your array below

```
let arr = [ ... ];
```

Then we filter the object with date grouped as keys

```
const g = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  let date = c.createdAt;
  if(!a[date]) {
    a[date] = [];
  }
  a[date].push(c);
  return a;
}, {});
```

return the filtered object as array with the generated array...

```
const groupedByDate = Object.keys(g).map(dt => {
  return { date:dt, values: g[dt] };
});

console.log(groupedByDate);
```